# TTreeView - Collapse and Expand Images not Alligned

Tags: delphi, treeview

Does anyone know how I can align the collapse/expand images with the center of my icon?
Using a white theme they are correct, but in the dark theme, the arrows seem to be bottom-aligned:

[image: Image of arrows not aligned]

Comment: I've noticed this issue but specifically when using styles.  If that's the case here you may want to add that note.

Comment: Which Delphi version? Which theme? I have now tried several of the themes in Delphi XE7, but haven't been able to reproduce.

Comment: Why don't you respond to my previous comment?

Comment: Sorry, It's Delphi 10.2, and the theme its made for our project, but I don't have access to it. It seems that the collapse icons have different sizes, but I have no idea where can I access and the collapse icons of the treeview.

Comment: Well, maybe you should ask the one who created the theme or style, since it obviously is related to your problem. If you can't say anything more specific about the theme or style, which ever it is, I really can't see how anybody here would able to help you.

Comment: There is any way that I can change de collapse image e realign myself??

Answer (score 0):

If you're using VCL Style Utils components, then modify UxTheme_TreeView in Vcl.Styles.UxTheme.pas

```
  case iPartId of
    TVP_GLYPH:
      begin
        LColor := StyleServices.GetSystemColor(clWindowText);
        LRect := pRect;
        LRect.Top := LRect.Top + 1; // <---- here's the change
        //LRect.Top := LRect.Top + 5;
        LRect.Left := LRect.Left + 5;

        if (iStateId = GLPS_OPENED) or (iStateId = HGLPS_OPENED) then
          DrawStyleArrow(hdc, TScrollDirection.sdDown, LRect.Location, 3, LColor)
        else
          DrawStyleArrow(hdc, TScrollDirection.sdRight, LRect.Location, 3, LColor);

        exit(S_OK);
      end;
```

Also set the tree view property `ShowLines := false;`